# Erro ao gerar migration depois de alterar um relacionamento

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, migrations

Estou tendo um erro ao mudar um relacionamento many to many no entity framework

Eu tinha 3 classes:

**Politica** 1-n **PoliticaNormativo** n-1 **Normativo**

Acontece que não queria mapear na mão essa tabela auxiliar, então deletei a classe PoliticaNormativo e no map de Politica fiz o seguinte:

```
this.HasMany(t => t.Politica)
            .WithMany(d => d.Normativo)
            .Map(d => {
                d.MapLeftKey("PoliticaID");
                d.MapRightKey("NormativoID");
                d.ToTable("PoliticaNormativo");
            });
```

Teoricamente essa alteração não deveria gerar nenhuma modificação, mas ao executar agora um add-migration eu tenho o seguinte erro:

> ```
>  System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<GetStoreAssociationTypePairs>d__70.MoveNext()
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__22`3.MoveNext()
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__63`1.MoveNext()
>    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.FindAssociationTypePairs(ICollection`1 entityTypePairs)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.Scaffold(String migrationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder scaffolder)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
>    at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>    at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
> Sequence contains no matching element
> ```

Politica:

```
public class Politica
{
    [Key]
    public int PoliticaID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome da Politica")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome é obrigatório.")]
    [StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Nome deve conter no máximo 80 caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data Registro")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Data Registro é obrigatório.")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public System.DateTime DataRegistro { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Início Vigência")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> VigenciaInicio { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fim Vigência")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> VigenciaFim { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status é obrigatório.")]
    public PoliticaStatus Status { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Revisão da Periodicidade")]
    [Range(1, 99, ErrorMessage = "Revisão da Periodicidade é obrigatória.")]
    public Nullable<int> PeriodicidadeRevisao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Resumo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Resumo é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(4000, ErrorMessage = "Campo Resumo deve conter até 4000 caracteres.")]
    public string Resumo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Criador Responsável")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Criador Responsável é obrigatório.")]
    public int CriadorID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Responsável da Alteração")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Responsável Alteração é obrigatório.")]
    public int UsuarioAlteracaoID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data de Alteração")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Data de Alteração é obrigatório.")]
    public DateTime DataAlteracao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Registro Excluido")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Registro Excluido é obrigatório.")]
    public Boleano IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Justificativa Exclusão")]
    [StringLength(4000, ErrorMessage = "Campo Justificativa Exclusão deve conter até 4000 caracteres.")]
    public string JustificativaDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Normativo> Normativo { get; set; }

}
```

Normativo:

```
public class Normativo : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public int NormativoID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Assunto")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Assunto é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Campo Assunto deve conter até 80 caracteres.")]
    public string Assunto { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Número")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Número do normativo é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Campo Número deve conter até 20 caracteres.")]
    public string Numero { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo Documento")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Tipo Documento é obrigatório.")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Tipo Documento é obrigatório.")]
    public int TipoDocumentoID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data Publicação")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Data da Publicação é obrigatório.")]
    public DateTime DataPublicacao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Início Vigência")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Início Vigência é obrigatório")]
    public DateTime VigenciaInicio { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fim Vigência")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> VigenciaFim { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Resumo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Resumo é obrigatório")]
    //[StringLength(2000, ErrorMessage = "Campo Resumo deve conter até 2000 caracteres.")] Removido pelo Campo do Conteudo do BacenIntegraca ser maior
    public string Resumo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Situação")]
    public Situacao Situacao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> DataSituacao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Justificativa")]
    [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Campo Justificativa deve conter até 1000 caracteres.")]
    public string JustificativaSituacao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Usuário")]
    public Nullable<int> UsuarioSituacao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Normativo> NormativoRelacionadoMaster { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Normativo> NormativoRelacionado { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Normativo> NormativoRevogadoMaster { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Normativo> NormativoRevogado { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Solicitacao> NormativoSolicitacao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Requisito> Requisito { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Politica> Politica { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NormativoControle> NormativoControle { get; set; }

    public virtual TipoDocumento TipoDocumento { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (VigenciaInicio < DataPublicacao)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Data de início vigência não pode ser menor que a data publicação.", new[] { "VigenciaInicio" });
        }

        if (NormativoID < 1)
        {
            Situacao = Situacao.Pendente;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia postar as entidades Politica e Normativa?

Comment: Você tem a tabela no banco e esta tentando executar o add-migration ?

Comment: @GabrielColetta adicionei as classes

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza sim porque fiz outras modificações também mas comentei elas pra procurar e o erro foi nessa modificação mesmo, mas também se não tivesse nada era pra gerar o migration vazio em vez de dar erro

Comment: @EduardoSampaio não posso dropar o banco o sistema está em produção

Comment: Seu comando executou normalmente ? acho que você teria que ter rodado o Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges .     
e depois o Update-Database

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza eu tentei rodar o add-migration "nome" apenas, oque o add-migration InitialCreate -IgnoreChanges faria?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx  This creates an empty migration with the current model as a snapshot.

Comment: Notei que o seu mapeamento de left e right key esta invertido, note que a descrição do método é: **the left/right foreign key points to the PARENT entity of the navigation property specified...** tente algo como: `d.MapLeftKey("NormativoID"); d.MapRightKey("PoliticaID");`. Me diga se isso corrige o erro.

Comment: @GabrielColetta realmente estava invertido, mas essa não era a causa do problema. Obrigado ia passar despercebido

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza acho que essa é realmente a melhor solução mas assim eu tenho que dar add com -IgnoreChanges só nas modificações que estão dando erro pra depois adicionar as outras, meio trabalhoso, sabe a causa desse erro?